# How to model the motion of a cone quantitatively in terms of torques?

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

Imagine that you apply a force to a cone that is laying on a horizontal plane. The cone moves in a circle upon application of the force but the question I have is how to quantitatively model the motion in terms of torques since the torque is different at every contact point(tip moves slower than ends of the cone)...

Comment: Does the surface have static friction to prevent the cone from sliding?

Comment: yes, it does have static friction

Comment: The motion is described in terms of the kinematics which describe all possible motions of a given geometry. Force play no role in kinematics.

Comment: See https://galileoandeinstein.phys.virginia.edu/7010/CM_24_Moments_of_Inertia.html

Comment: On this website, if you look at the expression for kinetic energy, there is still no way presented to evaluate the second derivative of the angle theta with respect to time even there as well. That is the fundamental problem that is arising.

Comment: Are there any external forces torques applied, besides gravity?

Comment: Nope. only friction, gravity, and the pushing force that is applied on the cone to initiate the motion are the main forces.

Comment: Can the cone both _slip_ and _roll_ depending on conditions?

Answer (score 1):

1. **Kinematics – Positions** Cone Height: $h$, Cone Radius: $r$, Cone Angle: $2\psi$

   $$\tan \psi = \tfrac{r}{h}$$
   $$\ell = \sqrt{h^2+r^2}$$

   [image: fig1]

   - Local to World Rotation Matrix - ${\rm R} = {\rm R}_\varphi {\rm R}_\psi {\rm R}_3$
     $$ {\rm R}_{\varphi}= \begin{vmatrix}
      \cos \varphi & -\sin \varphi & 0 \\
      \sin \varphi & \cos\varphi & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & 1 \end{vmatrix} $$
     $$  {\rm R}_{\psi}= \begin{vmatrix}
      \cos \psi & 0 & \sin \psi  \\
     0 & 1 & 0 \\
     - \sin \psi & 0 & \cos\psi  
     \end{vmatrix} $$
     $$  {\rm R}_3= 
     \begin{vmatrix}
      0 & 0 & 1\\
      1 & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & 1 & 0
      \end{vmatrix} $$
   - Point Positions- Apex **A**, Base **B**, Center of Mass **C**, Contact **K** $\def \bvec #1 {\boldsymbol{#1}}$

     $$ \bvec{r}_A =  \begin{pmatrix} 
     x \\
     y  \\
     0 
     \end{pmatrix}$$
     $$ \bvec{r}_C - \bvec{r}_A =  {\rm R}_{\varphi} \begin{pmatrix} 
     -\tfrac{3}{4} h \cos \psi \\
     0 \\
      \tfrac{3}{4} h \sin \psi 
     \end{pmatrix}$$
     $$\bvec{r}_B - \bvec{r}_A =  {\rm R}_{\varphi} \begin{pmatrix} 
     - h \cos \psi \\
     0 \\
      h \sin \psi 
     \end{pmatrix}$$
     $$\bvec{r}_K - \bvec{r}_A =  {\rm R}_{\varphi} \begin{pmatrix} 
     \text{-} h \cos \psi-r \sin \psi \\
     0  \\
     h \sin \psi -r \cos \psi 
     \end{pmatrix} = {\rm R}_{\varphi} \begin{pmatrix} \text{-}\ell\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix}$$
2. **Kinematics – Mass Moment of Inertia**

   - Local Coordinate System

     $${\rm I}_{\text body} = \begin{bmatrix} 
      \tfrac{3}{5} m h^2 + \tfrac{3}{20} m r^2 & & \\
     & \tfrac{3}{5} m h^2 + \tfrac{3}{20} m r^2 & \\
     & & \tfrac{3}{10} m r^2
     \end{bmatrix}$$
   - World Coordinate System

     $${\rm I}_C = {\rm R}_\varphi^\top \begin{bmatrix} 
     \frac{3 m r^2 (6 h^2+r^2)}{20 \ell^2} & & \frac{3 m r h (4 h^2-r^2)}{20 \ell^2} \\
      & \frac{3 m (4 h^2+r^2)}{20} &  \\
     \frac{3 m r h (4 h^2-r^2)}{20 \ell^2} & & \frac{3m (4 h^4 + h^2 r^2 + 2 r^2)}{20\ell^2} 
     \end{bmatrix} {\rm R}_\varphi$$
3. **Kinematics - Motion**

   Describe the motion (velocity and acceleration) of the body

   [image: fig3]

   - Rotational - Roll $\dot{\varphi}$, Spin $\dot{\theta}$

     $$ \begin{aligned}
     \bvec{\omega} & =\bvec{\hat{k}} \dot{\varphi} + {\rm R} \bvec{k} \dot{\theta} \\
       \bvec{\omega} & = {\rm R}_\varphi  \begin{pmatrix} 
     \dot{\varphi} \cot \psi \\ 0 \\ \dot{\varphi} - \dot{\theta} \sin \psi
     \end{pmatrix}
     \end{aligned}$$

     $$ \begin{aligned}
     \bvec{\alpha} & = \bvec{\hat{k}} \ddot{\varphi} + {\rm R} \bvec{k} \ddot{\theta} + (\bvec{\hat{k}} \dot{\varphi})\times {\rm R} \bvec{\hat{k}}  \dot{\theta} \\
       \bvec{\alpha} & = {\rm R}_\varphi  \begin{pmatrix} 
     \ddot{\theta} \cos \psi \\
     \dot{\theta}\, \dot{\varphi} \cos \psi \\
     \ddot{\varphi} - \ddot{\theta} \sin \psi
     \end{pmatrix}
     \end{aligned}$$
   - Translational - Center of Mass **C** and Contact Point **K**

   $$ \bvec{v}_C = \begin{pmatrix} \dot{x} \\ \dot{y} \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} +  {\rm R}_{\varphi}  \begin{pmatrix} 
   0 \\
   \text{-} \tfrac{3}{4} h \cos\psi \dot{\varphi}  \\
    0 
   \end{pmatrix}$$

   $$ \bvec{a}_C = \begin{pmatrix}\ddot{x} \\ \ddot{y} \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}  + {\rm R}_\varphi \begin{pmatrix} 
   \tfrac{3}{4} h \dot{\varphi}^2 \cos \psi \\
   \text{-} \tfrac{3}{4} h \ddot{\varphi} \cos \psi \\ 0
   \end{pmatrix}$$

   $$ \bvec{v}_K = \begin{pmatrix} \dot{x} \\ \dot{y} \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} +  {\rm R}_{\varphi}  \begin{pmatrix} 
   0 \\ r \dot{\theta} -\ell \dot{\varphi} \\ 0
   \end{pmatrix}$$

   $$ \bvec{a}_K = \begin{pmatrix}\ddot{x} \\ \ddot{y} \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}  + {\rm R}_\varphi \begin{pmatrix}
   \frac{ (\ell \dot{\varphi}-r \dot{\theta})^2 }{\ell} \\ 
   r \ddot{\theta} - \ell \ddot{\varphi} \\
   \frac{h r \dot{\theta}^2}{\ell}
   \end{pmatrix}$$

   - No Slip Conditions

     $$\ell \dot{\varphi} - r \dot{\theta} = 0$$
     $$\ell \ddot{\varphi} - r \ddot{\theta} = 0$$
4. **Dynamics - Forces** - Acting on the Apex **A**, the Contact Point **K** and the Center of Mass **C** for the weight.

   [image: fig4]

   - Translational

     $$ \begin{aligned}
     \bvec{F} & = \bvec{F}_A + \bvec{F}_K + \bvec{W}_C \\
     & \bvec{F}_A = {\rm R}_\varphi \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ S_A \\ N_A \end{pmatrix} & 
     & \bvec{F}_K = {\rm R}_\varphi \begin{pmatrix} F_K \\ S_K \\ N_K \end{pmatrix} &
     &  \bvec{W}_C = {\rm R}_\varphi \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ -m g \end{pmatrix} \\
      \bvec{F} & = {\rm R}_\varphi \begin{pmatrix} F_K \\ S_A+S_K \\ N_A+N_K - m g \end{pmatrix}
     \end{aligned}$$
   - Rotational

     $$\begin{aligned}
      \bvec{M}_C & = (\bvec{r}_A - \bvec{r}_C) \times  \bvec{F}_A + (\bvec{r}_K - \bvec{r}_C) \times  \bvec{F}_K \\
      \bvec{M}_C & = {\rm R}_\varphi \begin{pmatrix} 
     \tfrac{3 r}{4 \ell} h (S_A+S_K) \\
     \ell N_K - \tfrac{3 h}{4 \ell} ( h\, ( N_A+N_K)+ r\,F_K) \\
     -\ell S_K + \tfrac{3 h}{4 \ell} h (S_A+S_K)
     \end{pmatrix}
     \end{aligned}$$
   - Traction Requirement

     $$ \begin{aligned}
      S_A & \leq \mu N_A &
      \sqrt{S_K^2+F_K^2} & \leq \mu N_K \end{aligned}$$
5. **Equations Of Motion**

   - Translational

     $$\begin{aligned}
      \bvec{F} & = m\,\bvec{a}_C \\
      \begin{pmatrix} F_K \\ S_A+S_K \\ N_A+N_K - m g \end{pmatrix} & =m \left(  \begin{pmatrix} \ddot{x} \cos \varphi \\  \ddot{y} \sin \varphi \\ 0\end{pmatrix} +   \begin{pmatrix} 
     \tfrac{3}{4} h \dot{\varphi}^2 \cos \psi \\
     \text{-} \tfrac{3}{4} h \ddot{\varphi} \cos \psi \\ 0
     \end{pmatrix} \right)
     \end{aligned}$$
   - Rotational

   $$ \begin{aligned}
    \bvec{M}_C & = {\rm I}_C \bvec{\alpha} + \bvec{\omega} \times {\rm I}_C \bvec{\omega} \\
   \begin{pmatrix} 
   \tfrac{3 r}{4 \ell} h (S_A+S_K) \\
   \ell N_K - \tfrac{3 h}{4 \ell} ( h\, ( N_A+N_K)+ r\,F_K) \\
   -\ell S_K + \tfrac{3 h}{4 \ell} h (S_A+S_K)
   \end{pmatrix} & = \begin{bmatrix} 
   \frac{3 m r^2 (6 h^2+r^2)}{20 \ell^2} & & \frac{3 m r h (4 h^2-r^2)}{20 \ell^2} \\
    & \frac{3 m (4 h^2+r^2)}{20} &  \\
   \frac{3 m r h (4 h^2-r^2)}{20 \ell^2} & & \frac{3m (4 h^4 + h^2 r^2 + 2 r^2)}{20\ell^2} 
   \end{bmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 
   \ddot{\theta} \tfrac{h}{\ell} \\
   \dot{\theta}\, \dot{\varphi} \tfrac{h}{\ell} \\
   \ddot{\varphi} - \ddot{\theta} \tfrac{r}{\ell}
   \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\
   \tfrac{3 m h}{20 \ell^2} ( 4 \ell^2-5 r^2) ( r \dot{\varphi}^2 - \ell \dot \varphi \dot\theta) \\
    0 \end{pmatrix}
   \end{aligned}$$
6. **Solution for Pure Rolling**

   - Conditions for rolling

     $$  \begin{aligned} 
     \ddot{x}&=0 \\ 
     \ddot{y}&=0 \\ 
     \ddot{\theta} &= \ddot{\varphi} / \sin \psi \\
     \ddot{\varphi} &= 0 \\
     \end{aligned}$$
   - Solution for rolling

   $$\begin{aligned}
   F_K &= m \frac{3 h^2}{4 \ell} \dot{\varphi}^2 \\
   S_K & = 0 \\
   N_K & = m \left( \frac{3 h r (4 \ell^2+35 h^2)}{80 \ell^3} \dot{\varphi}^2 + \frac{3 h^2}{4 \ell^2} g \right) \\
   N_A &= - m \left( \frac{3 h r (4 \ell^2+35 h^2)}{80 \ell^3} \dot{\varphi}^2 + \frac{3 h^2 - 4 \ell^2}{4 \ell^2} g  \right) \\
   S_A &= 0
    \end{aligned}$$

   - Requirement for traction

     $$ \boxed{  \mu > \frac{1}{ \frac{g}{\ell \dot{\varphi}^2} + \frac{7 h r }{4 \ell^2} + \frac{r}{5 h}  }}$$

     Parametrize the roll speed $\dot{\varphi}^2 = \gamma \tfrac{g}{h}$ and plot the required friction coefficient for various cone angles.

     [image: fig6]

     The family of curves shown terminates at the red line when $\dot{\varphi}^2 \gg \tfrac{g}{h}$ (high-speed rolling) and the black lines is the locus of points containing the minimum and maximum friction requirement for each cone angle.

Comment: @ John No Slip conditions must contained the center of mass velocities ?

Comment: @Eli - I don't understand your question. Care to re-phrase. No-slip conditions tie the roll to the spin. I just chose this way to de-compose the cone's motion in a way that simplifies the kinematics the most.

Comment: Take disk  rolling on a plane, thus the velocity at the contact point is zero, you obtain 2 nonholonomic constraint equation that included the center of mass velocity .  the same here cone is rolling on the plane

Comment: Look here https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Classical_Mechanics/Graduate_Classical_Mechanics_(Fowler)/25%3A_Moments_of_Inertia_and_Rolling_Motion/25.02%3A_Analyzing_Rolling_Motion

Comment: If you parameterize the motion with $\omega$ and $v_C$ directly, you have 6 components and 5 constraints equations resulting in 1DOF in the system. I come from robotics where you reduce the system to a few DOF and tie together those DOF with constraints which makes the system much more manageable. In my case both $\omega$ and $v_C$ vectors are described in terms of the 2DOF, roll rate $\dot{\varphi}$, and spin rate $\dot{\theta}$. You do something similar in Lagrangian Mechanics where you have a smaller set of parameters $q$ to describe the kinematics. I still don't know what you are asking.

Comment: which drawing program do you use ?

Comment: @Eli - PowerPoint !!!!

Comment: sorry I meant the cone figure

Comment: @Eli - me too. I used PPT an insert a 3D solid. The floor is a line with depth and the rest is just lines with arrow heads. I also use [IguanaTex](https://www.jonathanleroux.org/software/iguanatex/download.html) to render $\LaTeX$ as pictures.

Answer (score 0):

The friction is static, so it has no inherent formula, only a maximum.  The friction will be as big as is necessary to prevent sliding, to provide the force needed to keep translational and rotational motions synchronized.

Because the cone does rotate around the tip, the friction must exert a total centripetal force to prevent the cone from sliding in a direction away from the tip.  All friction must be parallel to the horizontal plane.  Divide it into two components, parallel to the line of contact and perpendicular to the line of contact.  The pushing force would not contribute to torque around the symmetry axis.  You would need a temporarily unknown angular acceleration around the axis of symmetry that would be proportional to the angular acceleration of the cone around the vertical axis.

If the structure did not rotate around two perpendicular axes, then you could use the line of contact as the pivot to eliminate torque around the horizontal axis due to the static friction.  But you still need this for the torque around the vertical axis at the cone's tip.

Consider using the vertical axis through the tip and the axis of symmetry of the cone.  At any given point of contact, the radius from the tip is linearly proportional to the radius from the axis of symmetry.  The pushing force would not cause torque around the axis of symmetry.  If you could find the total torque due to static friction around the symmetry axis, it should be proportional to the corresponding torque around the vertical axis through the tip.  Friction components along the line of contact would not contribute to torque around either of these axes.